# linux raw socket, recv packet not belong to my netdevice

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, recv

A router have 60 tun devices, each configured with a valid ipv4 address, and 60 raw socket based on these devices respectively. And these socket all join a muticast group. And there are another device keeps sending multicast packets to these sockets.

If disable and then re-enable these interfaces, some interface would receive multicast packet that belong to other interface.

By disable interface, I mean close() socket;

By enable interface, I mean create socket using socket(), and setsockopt() such as SO_BINDTODEVICE, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP.

Specificly, If I disable interface1,2,3..,60, and then enable interface1,2,3..60, after enabling interface sometimes the first packet recevied from raw socket of interface N actually belong to interface(N-1).

I tcpdump the packet of interface N, and all packet are right, but the recv() of raw socket receive packet that belong to other interface.

Someone has any idea on this? Thanks!